# Can a boolean variable control a state chart?

Tags: anylogic

This statechart won't leave the Running state based on the condition of a boolean variable (lowCases). What am I doing wrong? Here's the code for the transition:

[image: transition code]

While in the Running state, the variable (lowCases) switches to TRUE but the state won't change:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: your answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888704/anylogic-why-does-my-condition-based-transition-not-work

Comment: Thank you Felipe. I've placed onChange() after my lowCases=true statement elseware in the model and now the transition works.  For my education, is there a way to set lowCases to true that will automatically be captured by the API Engine?

Comment: btw, best avoid conditional transitions entirely. Not only is it easy to miss them not firing (as in your case) but also they can eat up considerable computing power in larger models for nothing (since they are checked at every event). Also, you can *always* replace it with event- or msg-based transitions elegantly :-)

Comment: Good to know @Benjamin. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AnyLogic - Why does my condition based transition not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888704/anylogic-why-does-my-condition-based-transition-not-work)